# How can I make my SQL scalar function deterministic as well as having a variable default value in it

Tags: sql-server

```
--DROP FUNCTION fn_NonDeterministic;
--DROP FUNCTION fn_Deterministic

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_NonDeterministic]()
RETURNS DECIMAL (13,3)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @date AS DATETIME = '01/01/1900';
    RETURN 10.2
END
GO


SELECT ROUTINE_NAME,
       IS_DETERMINISTIC
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE  ROUTINE_NAME = 'fn_NonDeterministic'
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Deterministic]()
RETURNS DECIMAL (13,3)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @date AS DATETIME ;
    RETURN 10.2
END
GO


SELECT ROUTINE_NAME,
       IS_DETERMINISTIC
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE  ROUTINE_NAME = 'fn_Deterministic'
```

Comment: if you change the date to nvarchar, it becomes deteministic - all I can think of is that the conversion of the string to date is somehow flagged as non-deterministic

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it likes the conversion from string to date, which is deterministic since it is affected by regional setting .

```
/*
dROP FUNCTION fn_NonDeterministic;
DROP FUNCTION fn_Deterministic
*/


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_NonDeterministic]()
RETURNS DECIMAL (13,3)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    -- ********************************  this changes things ***********
    DECLARE @date AS datetime = datefromparts(1970,05,23);
    RETURN 10.2
END
GO


SELECT ROUTINE_NAME,
       IS_DETERMINISTIC
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE  ROUTINE_NAME = 'fn_NonDeterministic'
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Deterministic]()
RETURNS DECIMAL (13,3)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @date AS DATETIME ;
    RETURN 10.2
END
GO


SELECT ROUTINE_NAME,
       IS_DETERMINISTIC
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE  ROUTINE_NAME = 'fn_Deterministic'
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me, but now getting following error. Computed column cannot be persisted because the column does user or system data access.